# Prevent swap formating at OS installation

Tags: partitioning, swap, installer, fstab

For testing I've created multiple partitions (7) to install different Linux distributions.

I have a partition `/dev/sda6` for Linux Swap.

Each installer (graphical install) decides to reformat this swap everytime I install a new distribution. This means `/dev/sda6` have a new **UUID**.

The problem is that all the other distributions on other partition now have an invalid **UUID** for the swap in the `/etc/fstab`. (and sometimes also in the `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`).

This pose the problem of slowing down the booting of all already installed partitions because it tries to mount a invalid **UUID** for 1 minute before timeout.

So I have to go in each distibutions to update the `/etc/fstab`.

Is there anyway to prevent the swap from being reformatted at every new distribution installation (when I format a new partition) ?

Or could I find a way to set a fixed **UUID** to the swap even if it's being reformatted ?

Or maybe I could have a postinstall script that updates the `/etc/fstab` of each partition but I don't really know if I can control the post install of graphical installers to trigger a custom script. (Note: I'm using Ventoy on external hard drive to boot from multiple live installer iso)

Comment: Change the partition type code / uuid temporary? So that it does not look like a swap partition. (You'll have to add an entry to the fstab for it manually for every new installation though).

Comment: It still doesn't help much if I have to add the entry manually.